# Excel "true-false" to checked boxes

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I'm generating from a SharePoint dashboard. It's turning my checkboxes in the SharePoint table to "true" or "false" values in the Excel spreadsheet. I wanted to know if it is possible to turn those "true" or "false" values back into checked boxes, with the appropriate check or uncheck option selected.

Any help at all is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly advise against using check boxes in Excel if you already have the data as TRUE/FALSE in a cell. Check box controls are meant to be for user forms, and even though they can be placed in the spreadsheet grid, they live in a layer on top of the spreadsheet. Yes, they can be linked to a spreadsheet cell, but this is cumbersome.

Instead of using a macro that inserts a check box for each data row you could use a helper column with a formula along the lines of

=IF([@checkBoxField],"a","r")

Then format the helper column with the Marlett font, which will show the letter "a" as a tick and the letter "r" as a cross.

[image]

Applying a formula like this will be much faster than inserting check box controls into each row and linking them to the field cells.

Comment: wow, I love this solution. +1. It's unfortunate that we cannot do it in-place on the same column. But well, we can eventually "hide" the original column (if we dont need to edit it).

Comment: Yes, a helper column would be required. But you could also use a formula like `=[@checkBoxField]*1`, which will return 1 0r 0. Then use custom format `\a;;\r` on the column and format with Marlett. Now you can edit the helper column with 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE. This will break the formula for that row, but at least the data entry is easier to remember than "a" for True and "r" for False.

Comment: Thank you! I agree, I'd much rather skip the check boxes but I'm intending to use the spreadsheet in a presentation, and checks and crosses are more aesthetically pleasing than the TRUE/FALSE values (though it wouldn't matter to me, personally).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a checkbox over a given cell, then edit its properties (Format Control --> Control Tab) and set its `Cell Link` property to the address of the cell; i.e. "B2". If you have too many such boolean cells, the task is tedious so you might need to automate it with VBA.

p.s. I agree with @teylyn that this shouldn't be a good choice if you have a huge column of boolean data; it adds too many shapes which is cumbersome. You should use it if the number of boolean cells is rather limited.

[image]